# Android: EditText returning same value as contents

Tags: java, android, sql, database, android-edittext

The method below is responsible for inserting a new record to a database table and it is called when a `button` is pressed. However the String input that is assigned the value of the contents of the `EditText` never seems to be assigned to the new contents whenever a new value is typed in.

As a result inserting a new record only works once.

Any suggestions why this happens would be appreciated.

```
public void insertRecord(View additionBut) {
        System.out.println("NOW INSIDE THE INSERT RECORD");
        input = addTextInput.getText().toString();
        addTextInput.getText().clear();
        System.out.println(input);
        if (purpose.equals("ViewNovel")) {
            md.addPiece(input, "0");
        } else if (purpose.equals("ViewPlay")) {
            md.addPiece(input, "1");
        } else {
            // whatever else
        }

        displayList();
    }
```

Comment: What is the object called purpose and additionBut is also never used, is this on purpose?

Comment: 'purpose' is a String holding the purpose of the insertion, i.e. if the novels are being viewed, it inserts the 'input' along with a 0, representing a novel. The View additionBut parameter is because in the XML, that view being pressed (button) calls this method.

Answer (score 1):

You can also clear your EditText in another way, Try following way,

```
public void insertRecord(View additionBut) {
        System.out.println("NOW INSIDE THE INSERT RECORD");
        input = addTextInput.getText().toString();
        addTextInput.setText("")                              // Change here
        System.out.println(input);
        if (purpose.equals("ViewNovel")) {
            md.addPiece(input, "0");
        } else if (purpose.equals("ViewPlay")) {
            md.addPiece(input, "1");
        } else {
            // whatever else
        }

        displayList();
    }
```

Comment: I also tried this, but unfortunately then input remains always an empty String, the problem seems to be that the new text that is typed into the EditText is not being assigned to the 'input'.

Comment: just from a small code, I can not assume what you want to do. You should upload more relavant code.

Comment: I had a more complete code listing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21216687/android-method-to-add-to-database-attempts-to-add-same-record-twice?noredirect=1#comment31954121_21216687

Comment: However this was deemed too extensive, I need to find a compromise.

Answer (score 0):

Place

```
displayList();
addTextInput.getText().clear(); //after displayList();
```

May be the reference is same. Because of that when you try to clear the edit text the value in input getting reflected. If so, try creating new String object with the value in the edit text box.